# C# Transparent Panels Refresh Problems

Tags: c#, animation, transparency, picturebox, panels

I'm currently working on a project that requires animation on a transparent panel. I have been able to create a transparent panel and draw on it, but when I refresh the panel, where I have drawn with the pen tool is not being redrawn as transparent. This is leaves the last position of what I drew previously stained on the panel.

I assume there is a simple way to override OnPaint or Refresh to redraw all of the pixels on the panel as transparent, but I can't find a solution online or figure it out myself.

Here is the code I used to make the background transparent:

```
public class TransparentPanel : Panel
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
    }
 }
```

This was my best failed attempt to redraw the background as transparent:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
{
        pe.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100,255,255,255)), this.ClientRectangle);
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the background becomes opaque white after a couple refreshes.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I'm super new to graphics and animation, and I assume this has a fairly simple answer. Thanks in advance.

---

****EDIT**********
As per Dyppl's response I have changed the way I draw the graphics to the panel. Here is my current code:

```
    public TransparentPanel fighterPanel;
...
    fighterPanel.Paint +=new PaintEventHandler(fighterPanel_Paint);
...
    fighterPanel = new TransparentPanel();
    fighterPanel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(600, 300);
    fighterPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 400);
    gameArenaForm.Controls.Add(fighterPanel);
    fighterPanel.BringToFront();        
...
    private void fighterPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Pen blackPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3), redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3), bluePen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 3))
        {
            //head     
            e.Graphics.DrawEllipse
                (blackPen,
                head.DrawPoint(torso.GetTorsoAngle(), torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY()).X,
                head.DrawPoint(torso.GetTorsoAngle(), torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY()).Y,
                head.radius * 2,
                head.radius * 2
                );
            //torso
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY(), torso.shoulders.getLocationX(), torso.shoulders.getLocationY());
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.shoulders.getLocationX(), torso.shoulders.getLocationY(), torso.hips.getLocationX(), torso.hips.getLocationY());
            //right arm
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.shoulders.getLocationX(), torso.shoulders.getLocationY(), rightArm.elbow.getLocationX(), rightArm.elbow.getLocationY());
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, rightArm.elbow.getLocationX(), rightArm.elbow.getLocationY(), rightArm.attachHand.getLocationX(), rightArm.attachHand.getLocationY());
            //left arm
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.shoulders.getLocationX(), torso.shoulders.getLocationY(), leftArm.elbow.getLocationX(), leftArm.elbow.getLocationY());
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(bluePen, leftArm.elbow.getLocationX(), leftArm.elbow.getLocationY(), leftArm.attachHand.getLocationX(), leftArm.attachHand.getLocationY());
            //right leg
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.hips.getLocationX(), torso.hips.getLocationY(), rightLeg.knee.getLocationX(), rightLeg.knee.getLocationY());
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(redPen, rightLeg.knee.getLocationX(), rightLeg.knee.getLocationY(), rightLeg.attachFoot.getLocationX(), rightLeg.attachFoot.getLocationY());
            //left leg
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.hips.getLocationX(), torso.hips.getLocationY(), leftLeg.knee.getLocationX(), leftLeg.knee.getLocationY());
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(bluePen, leftLeg.knee.getLocationX(), leftLeg.knee.getLocationY(), leftLeg.attachFoot.getLocationX(), leftLeg.attachFoot.getLocationY());
        }
    }
```

Here are some pictures of before and after the object moves and refreshes a few times:

[Before](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0ZghwqWgbQWODljODY1OGQtNzBjYS00ZTA3LWE1MGItNzUyMjIyMWU5NGEz&hl=en_US&authkey=CNGLv_4B)

[After](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B0ZghwqWgbQWYmNjODkzMWMtZGM5OC00ZjRjLThhZjItZGNkMGI0OWZkNjNm&hl=en_US&authkey=CMHX99UF)

Sorry, it won't let me embed the images unless I have 10 Rep.

Comment: From a guy who's not really new to graphics: transparency is never fairly simple when it comes to GDI+ and winforms...

Comment: Ewe, that doesn't sound very hopeful for me then. Do you have any ideas about this problem?

Comment: @Alex: yes, trying it right now

Comment: @Alex: how do you draw on the panel?

Comment: @Dyppl2: 
private Graphics drawIt;
...
drawIt = fighterPanel.CreateGraphics();
...
drawIt.DrawEllipse(blackPen,
                    head.DrawPoint(torso.GetTorsoAngle(), torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY()).X,
                    head.DrawPoint(torso.GetTorsoAngle(), torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY()).Y,
                    head.radius * 2,
                    head.radius * 2
                    );
drawIt.DrawLine(blackPen, torso.neck.getLocationX(), torso.neck.getLocationY(), torso.shoulders.getLocationX(), torso.shoulders.getLocationY());

Comment: @Alex: make sure you use "@Dyppl", not "@Dyppl2", otherwise I won't be notified about your comments

Comment: @Dyppl: Sorry about that I'm new to the community and didn't know what that was for. I didn't notice the "2" at the end. I think I grabbed it off the time stamp after your name.

Comment: @Alex: that's no problem, notifications just help people to react more quickly when you address your comments to them

Comment: "After" picture doesn't open for some reason..

Comment: @Dyppl: Give it a try now, I updated the security settings on the photo in google docs.

Comment: Yeah, I understand the problem now. You should call `Graphics.Clear(Color)` in the beginning of your paint handler. The problem is that it will mess up your transparency. Trying to figure it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `CreateGraphics` for your task. Subscribe to the `Paint` event of your panel and do all your drawing in the event handler using `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` as a `Graphics` object instead.

```
private void transparentPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red,2), 4,4,64,64);
}
```

Here's what I got using your `TransparentPanel` and my event handler:

[image: Result image]

**UPDATE:** The problem is that you have to call `Graphics.Clear` method in the beginning of every draw cycle in order to get rid of all previous drawings. It will mess up your transparent background. [This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226091810/http://www.bobpowell.net/transcontrols.htm) gives you some advices regarding the problem. The Key point is that you should invalidate the parent control of your panel as well to get your "transparent" background.

So, I left the code of `TransparentPanel` untouched but changed the code of main form:

```
readonly Random _rand =new Random();

private void transparentPanel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red,2), _rand.Next(60),_rand.Next(30),64,64);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Invalidate(new Rectangle(transparentPanel1.Location, transparentPanel1.Size),true);
}
```

Now, whenever I click the button on my form the panel gets redrawn and shows one rectangle in random location. If you invalidate the transparantPanel1 itself, it won't clear and you'll see a mess of red rectangles.

---

***UPDATED (By Alex):***
This is the code provided in the link from Dyppl that solved the problem. It just needs to be placed in the transparent panel class:

```
public void InvalidateEx()
    {
        if (Parent == null)
            return;
        Rectangle rc = new Rectangle(this.Location, this.Size);
        Parent.Invalidate(rc, true);
    }
```

I call this code at every refresh on the panel and it keeps the background transparent.

Comment: Awesome, let me give it a shot.

Comment: @Dyppl: I messed around with this a lot and it is still causing the same problem as with CreateGraphics. I'm going to add my actual updated code using your suggestion to my question along with some screen shots.

Comment: @Dyppl: I'm pretty sure I implemented this the way you expected me too. If I missing something can you let me know where? You can see the code and pics in my edit.

Comment: @Dyppl: You're awesome. The InvalidateEx function fixed the problem for me. My animation now runs and remains transparent. Thank you so much for you time and your help.

Comment: @Alex: no problems, feel free to mark an answer as accepted if it helped you and welcome to the site!